# Обработка ответа Serial

Tags: arduino

У меня есть устройство sim800l, с которым я общаюсь AT командам. `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS";`

Функцию loop принимает и обрабатывает, а так-же выводит в консоль ответ модуля.

```
void loop()
{

  if (Serial3.available()){
      Serial.write(Serial3.read()); 
   }

   if (Serial.available()){
    Serial3.write(Serial.read());
   }

}
```

Вводя AT команду `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS";` Я получаю ответ OK или ERROR.

Я хочу обрабатывать ответы с помощью условного оператора if.

В интернете находил ответы, но они не работают для меня.

```
int x;
String str;

void loop() 
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        x = Serial.parseInt();
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697047/convert-serial-read-into-a-useable-string-using-arduino)

Вычитал в интернете, что можно использовать вот эти функции для определения ответа.

```
String sendATCommand(String cmd, bool waiting) {
  String _resp = "";                            // Переменная для хранения результата
  Serial.println(cmd);                          // Дублируем команду в монитор порта
  SIM800.println(cmd);                          // Отправляем команду модулю
  if (waiting) {                                // Если необходимо дождаться ответа...
    _resp = waitResponse();                     // ... ждем, когда будет передан ответ
    // Если Echo Mode выключен (ATE0), то эти 3 строки можно закомментировать
    if (_resp.startsWith(cmd)) {  // Убираем из ответа дублирующуюся команду
      _resp = _resp.substring(_resp.indexOf("\r", cmd.length()) + 2);
    }
    Serial.println(_resp);                      // Дублируем ответ в монитор порта
  }
  return _resp;                                 // Возвращаем результат. Пусто, если проблема
}

String waitResponse() {                         // Функция ожидания ответа и возврата полученного результата
  String _resp = "";                            // Переменная для хранения результата
  long _timeout = millis() + 10000;             // Переменная для отслеживания таймаута (10 секунд)
  while (!SIM800.available() && millis() < _timeout)  {}; // Ждем ответа 10 секунд, если пришел ответ или наступил таймаут, то...
  if (SIM800.available()) {                     // Если есть, что считывать...
    _resp = SIM800.readString();                // ... считываем и запоминаем
  }
  else {                                        // Если пришел таймаут, то...
    Serial.println("Timeout...");               // ... оповещаем об этом и...
  }
  return _resp;                                 // ... возвращаем результат. Пусто, если проблема
}
```

[Источник](http://codius.ru/articles/GSM_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C_SIM800L_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_2)

Comment: Что означает "не работают"? Раз не работают, то нужно исправить, чтоб работало.

Comment: У меня программа начинает глючить. Ответ приходит побуквенно с задержкой.К примеру S(1с)M(1с)S. 1с это примерная задержка до появления сл. символа.

Comment: сделал по другому, так ответ не может прийти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String - очень медленный класс. У меня строку в виде "SYNC_R000000000000000END" распарсивало этим классом очень долго, порядка секунды.

В итоге написал так: 
1) ищем начало пакета (т е SYNC_)
1.1) если нашлось - продолжаем алгоритм. если нет - ждем еще, вдруг это приходят остатки прошлого пакета данных. Заодно взводим таймер на отслеживание таймаута
2) ищем конец пакета (т е END). действуем аналогично 1.1
3) далее получаем индекс начала данных(т е вся строка может содержать к примеру такой текст "мусорSYNC_R000000000000000ENDросум") и конца данных. На основе этих индексов получаем полезные данные.

Для поиска использовал обычную, быструю, но самописную функцию поиска подстроки в строке. Т е брал и тупо сравнивал каждый байт с шаблоном. если совпала последовательность - подстрока нашлась.

Что бы отладить все это, убедитесь что строка от модуля приходит вся целиком, без повреждений. а дальше дело техники ее распарсить. Если нужен пример - скину чуть позже

Comment: Спасибо. Пожалуйста, скиньте пример.

Comment: К сожалению в коммент не влазит весь текст. Код можно посмотреть здесь:  [ссылка](https://github.com/XanderEVG/doorbell/blob/master/doorbell.ino)  (метод check_sync).  Если кратко - ждем пока придет весь пакет данных, потом:  for(byte i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
          if(data_array[i]!=start_str[i])
          {
            //Взводим флаг ошибки
            correct_string=false;
            break;
          }
        }

Comment: start_str - это строка шаблон начала пакета. к приеру пакет выглядит так: SYNC_R000000000000000END. тогда start_str="SYNC_"

Comment: Спасибо, в целом я понял как работает ваш метод. А вот ` for(byte i=17; i<32; i++) { error_message[i]=' '; }` обязательно выполнять? Я просто думаю, по дефолту массив должен быть заполнен самостоятельно, при инициализации.